# How do you use a respawn anchor in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I crafted a respawn anchor, but it doesn't seem to do anything. What do I have to do to make it useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To make a [respawn anchor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Respawn_Anchor) usable, you must do the following:**

- Go to the nether
- Place it where you want to respawn
- Use 1-4 [glowstone blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glowstone) on it to give it the equivalent number of charges.
- "Use" the respawn anchor (in the same way you'd open a door)

Afterward, if you die in any dimension, the respawn anchor will use a charge to respawn you at its location.

*Warning*: Don't try to set your spawn point at a respawn anchor in the Overworld or The End. If you do, it will explode (similar to when you use a bed in the Nether).

Comment: However, I'm playing minecraft hardcore, so is it completely useless then? (except for the achievement)

Comment: @DarthOverlord Essentially. If you can't respawn, then it's only useful as decoration or to get the Java-edition _advancement_. FWIW, in Bedrock, there's no _achievement_ associated with the Respawn Anchor.

Comment: It can also be used to set where you will return from the end to.